# Why I do not get radio button value with php?

Tags: php, html, forms, radio-button, http-post

I´m passing a value of a radio button in a page with a form and I want to get the value of the selected option in another php file, but I can´t get that value.

First page:

```
<form class="itemSelection" action="../php/itemSelection1Save.php"><br><br>
    <h1>Recommended Item(s)</h1>
    <table class="itemTableRecom">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Selected Item Type</th>
                <th>Recommended Item Type</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            foreach ($_SESSION['itemsInfo'] as $row) {
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="selectedItem" id="selectedItem" required="" value="<?php echo $row[0] ?>"></td>
                    <td><?php
                        echo row[0]</td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Next"/>
</form>
```

Second file:

```
$_SESSION['selectedItem1'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'selectedItem');

filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'selectedItem')
```

returns nothing

Comment: you missed a $. `echo row[0]` (for a start)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You form is with method `get` (the default method if not specified):

```
<form class="itemSelection" action="../php/itemSelection1Save.php">
```

insert `method='post'`:

```
<form class="itemSelection" action="../php/itemSelection1Save.php" method='post'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the following changes in HTML part , add method="post"

```
<form class="itemSelection" action="../php/itemSelection1Save.php" method="post">
```

Make the following change in PHP part (optional):

Also add filter_option in filter_input. filter the ID or name of the filter to use. Default is FILTER_DEFAULT, which results in no filtering.

```
filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'selectedItem',filter_option)
```

Answer (score 0):

You Need To Add The Form Method you can try my code i simply code for you hopefully it will work!

```
<form class="itemSelection" method="post" action="../php/itemSelection1Save.php">
    <h1>Recommended Item(s)</h1>
    <table class="itemTableRecom">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Selected Item Type</th>
                <th>Recommended Item Type</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php 

                foreach ($_SESSION['itemsInfo'] as $row) {

                ?>

                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" name="selectedItem" value="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>"></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row[0]; ?></td>
                </tr>    

              <?php } ?>   

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next">
</form>
```